# Content of an element of the array in VBA

Tags: arrays, string, vba

I want to know how to check if nth element of an array in VBA contains certain character - e.g. total content is "My email address is a.asdf@xyz.com" so the array elements would be "My", "email", "address" etc. and one of them would be "a.asdf@xyz.com".
I need to know which element starts with "a." and then print that element of that array.

Answer (score 1):

This should show you the basic idea

```
Sub ArrayCheck()
    Dim myArray(1 To 5) As String
    myArray(1) = "My"
    myArray(2) = "email"
    myArray(3) = "address"
    myArray(4) = "a.asdf@xyz.com"
    myArray(5) = "some other stuff"

    Dim strElement As Variant
    For Each strElement In myArray
        If strElement Like "a.*" Then
            MsgBox "Hit: " & strElement
        End If
    Next strElement
End Sub
```